# Unable to find exact address by company name with google map api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When we search for a location with company name for example,

Vacaville Animal Care Center, Vacaville, CA

at http://maps.google.com, we are getting directly the exact location details like,

***Vacaville Animal Care Center,
1100 East Monte Vista Avenue,
Vacaville, CA 95688, United States
+1 707-514-3456
vacavilleanimalcarecenter.com‎***

But when we make request to google map api, as per the documentation provided, for example,

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Vacaville+Animal+Care+Center,+Vacaville,+CA&sensor=false

Im not getting the exact details.

Is there anything I'm missing in my request? Please point me in right direction

Comment: what are you wanting to happen, the infowindow to open with all the address details etc?  For that, you'll need to create your own infowindow and supply it with your content yourself.  And to add a marker at the latitude & longitude of your address

Comment: Hi Duncan, no, I'm trying to make a simple request to retrieve address details to store in my database.

Comment: I have updated my question to give more info, as you can see above, I'm getting exact details of business via http://maps.google.com, I want those details which are not coming when I make a simple API request to store in my database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Places API:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/